# Некорректная работа баллона на iPhone 5S/SE

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

При открытии баллона на iPhone 5S/SE содержимое, которое должно отображаться в нижней части карты уплываем ниже контейнера карты и как следствие отображается не полностью.

https://rosdikoros.ru/ -> открыть карту, вкладка "Заготовители".

В эмуляторе в Chrome работает корректно. Не очень понятно как отладить и выяснить причину.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У вас изначально неправильный размер карты в мобильном Safari. `$('body').height()` возвращает не высоту вьюпорта, а высоту документа, вам нужен `$(window).height()`.

А еще лучше - используйте [flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) и отдайте расчет размеров на откуп браузеру.